# Divisibility in base $7$ problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

Find all integers between $0 \leq a \leq 2400$ such they are divisible by $8$ and that their base 7 development has at least $3$ equal digits.

Comment: What sort of class is this?  (That will have some impact on the approach...)  Number theory is my guess, but it is possible that a programming class would ask a similar question.

Comment: Number theory, indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base 7 a number is divisible by 8 if and only if the alternating sum of its digits is divisible by 8.

If 3 digits are equal, and the alternating sum is divisible by 8, the 4th digit must also be equal.

Therefore, the answers are 0000, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, and 6666 (all written in base 7). (I am not sure if you would characterize 0000 as having 3 equal digits or not).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  As $7^4=2401$ the numbers $a$ have at most four digits in base $7$, three of which must be equal.  The divisibility test for $11$ in base $10$ (add up the even places and subtract the odd places) is actually a test for $b+1$ in base $b$, so will give you an easy check for divisibility by $8$.  There not many numbers to check.

Answer (score 0):

What is the smallest 3 digit number in base 7?  the largest?